# Let $K/F$ be a field extension. If $\alpha \in F(\alpha^m)$, $m > 1$, then $\alpha$ is algebraic in $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $K/F$ be a field extension. If $\alpha \in F(\alpha^m)$, $m > 1$, then $\alpha$ is algebraic in $F$.

A proof provided in the book is as follows:

*Proof:* Since $\alpha \in F(\alpha^m)$, there exists $f$ and $g$ in $F[x]$ such that $\alpha = \frac{f(a^m)}{g(a^m)}$. Therefore, $\alpha$ is the solution to the polynomial $h(x) := xg(x^m) - f(x^m)$. Suppose $\deg(f(x)) = s, \deg(g(x))=t$. Then $\deg(f(x^m)) = sm$ and $\deg(g(x^m)) = tm$. Since $m>1$, $ms \neq mt + 1$. Therefore, $h \neq 0$, showing that $\alpha \in F(\alpha^m)$.

**My question**: Why we have those $f$ and $g$ satisfies $a = \frac{f(a^m)}{g(a^m)}$? Does it imply that $s \neq t$?

Comment: Equivalently with $x$ transcendental then $x \not \in F(x^m)$ for $m > 1$.

Comment: What is the form of the elements in $F (\alpha^m)$?

Comment: @xbh I am not quite sure, I just thought that $F(\alpha^m)$ is just the smallest subfield of $K$ joining $\alpha^m$. Could you further explain?

Comment: @mathdoge Same as what Robert Shore says. $F(\alpha) \cong$ the fraction field of $F[\alpha]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of $F(\alpha^m)$ is the set of quotients of polynomials in $\alpha^m$.  We’re choosing two specific polynomials, $f$ and $g$, so that their quotient witnesses that $\alpha \in F(\alpha^m)$.  That means $\alpha=\frac{f(\alpha^m)}{g(\alpha^m)}$.  Your question uses $a$ here instead of $\alpha$.  Perhaps that’s the source of your confusion.

It’s possible that $s=t$; that won’t affect the proof, which demonstrates that there’s a non-zero polynomial $h(x)=xg(x^m)-f(x^m)$ with the property $h(\alpha)=0$.  The existence of that polynomial means (by the definition of algebraic) that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I indeed made a typo ($\alpha$ and $a$). However I am still not sure, I thought $F(\alpha^m)$ is just the smallest subfields of $K$ containing  $\alpha^m$, and $K$ is algebraic over $F$ says that we could find a polynomial, say $p(x) \in F[x]$ such that $p(\alpha^m) = 0$. Could you further explain your first paragraph?

Comment: The smallest subfield containing $F$ and $\alpha^m$ has to contain all $F$-polynomials in $\alpha^m$ and all fractions of such polynomials.  If you haven’t already done so, you should prove that the set of such fractions (with non-zero denominators) is in fact a field, which must therefore be the smallest such field.